# Sample Size Calculation Using Wilson Score

Tags: sample-size

I am using a number of different sample size methods to compare their usefulness for a particular study. One of these is the Wilson Score Method. I am searching for a table or chart of the sample size using this method for different estimated proportions so that I can compare with the work I've already done. Does anyone have such a table or can point me in the right direction?